# Can a person's soul reincarnate into multiple bodies simultaneously?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, soul, reincarnation

Is it possible that a soul of some person, say John, reincarnates into multiple bodies but those bodies are all alive in the same period, so they are all alive in the same year, etc. or is this only possible for components of a soul like component 1 ends up with one body, component 2 with a different body etc. and then at death, it recombines (if purpose for gilgul was achieved?)?

Comment: I don't have sources handy but the consensus is whatever is here today is mainly crumbs and remixes from past souls, there's a big progressive decline after Abraham. And yes different people get different parts at the same time for example soul mates.

Comment: Guys, this question is about Kabbalah and thus, presupposes the truth of reincarnation as explicated by Zohar, Sha'ar HaGilgulim, etc. for the question to be answerable. This comment section is not a place to debate whether you believe reincarnation is legitimate or not - make a private chat for that.